# Sorting an object of nested objects in javascript (maybe using lodash?)

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I have an object of nested objects and would like to sort by one of the nested values (e.g. "month_sales" descending). This is what the data looks like:

```
{ 
"Bob": { sales: 13, revenue: 33, month_sales: 149 },
"Bill": { today_sales: 20, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 186 },
"Jane": { today_sales: 17, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 164 }
}
```

This is what I want it to look like (sort by month_sales descending):

```
{ 
"Bill": { today_sales: 20, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 186 },
"Jane": { today_sales: 17, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 164 }
"Bob": { sales: 13, revenue: 33, month_sales: 149 },
}
```

I have looked all over Google and StackOverflow, and have only found a couple answers that deal with sorting an object rather than an array, and in every case the answer has been along the lines of "write a function to convert the object to an array, sort that, and then turn it back into an object."

I'm willing to do that as a last resort, but it seems like I should be able to do this without deconstructing the entire object and putting it back together again. Maybe there's an elegant way to do this in lodash or something?

Comment: Please check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have sorted arrays, not objects. To do that, you first need to *map* your object to an array. Here's how you can do it using lodash [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) and [sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy):

```
_(data)
    .map(function(value, key) {
        return _.defaults({ name: key }, value);
    })
    .sortBy('name')
    .value();
// →
// [
//   { name: "Bill", today_sales: 20, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 186 },
//   { name: "Bob", sales: 13, revenue: 33, month_sales: 149 },
//   { name: "Jane", today_sales: 17, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 164 }
// ]
```

The mapping uses the [defaults()](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults) function to give each array item a new `name` property, which is used to sort the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because properties of objects do not have a guaranteed order in javascript. You will have to convert it to an array perhaps like this first:

```
[ 
  { name: "Bob", sales: 13, revenue: 33, month_sales: 149 },
  { name: "Bill", today_sales: 20, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 186 },
  { name: "Jane", today_sales: 17, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 164 }
]
```

Then when you sort it as an array it will maintain that order.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your object to an array, then you could sort them by category like this

```
var arr = [ 
  { name: "Bob", sales: 13, revenue: 33, month_sales: 149 },
  { name: "Bill", today_sales: 20, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 186 },
  { name: "Jane", today_sales: 17, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 164 }
]

arr.sort(function(x, y){
    var category = "month_sales"
    if (x[category] < y[category]) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (x[category] > y[category]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can't sort an object, you can create an index sorted on whatever property you want, e.g. to get a list of the names sorted by *month_sales* highest to lowest:

```
var obj = { 
"Bob": { sales: 13, revenue: 33, month_sales: 149 },
"Bill": { today_sales: 20, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 186 },
"Jane": { today_sales: 17, week_sales: 38, month_sales: 164 }
}

var index = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a,b) {
              return obj[b].month_sales - obj[a].month_sales;
            });
```

Then get the one with the highest value:

```
console.log(index[0] + ':' + obj[index[0]].month_sales); // Bill:186
```