# Javascript Object sorting by value object - using ES2020

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to sort this data based on number of employees using JavaScript

```
const companies = {
   'landwaves ltd': {employees: 1200, worth: '1.2m', CEO: 'Rajiv Bansal'},
   'colin & co': {employees: 200, worth: '0.2m', CEO: 'Sukesh Maheshwari'},
   'motilal biscuits': {employees: 975, worth: '1m', CEO: 'Rahul Gupta'},
   'numbtree': {employees: 1500, worth: '1.5m', CEO: 'Jay Kumar'},
   'solace pvt ltd': {employees: 1800, worth: '1.65m', CEO: 'Arvind Sangal'},
   'ambicure': {employees: 170, worth: '0.1m', CEO: 'Preetam Chawla'},
   'dis n dat': {employees: 540, worth: '1m', CEO: 'Mohit Sharma'},
}
```

I have tried with below function but it return as Array, is there any better way to solve this.

```
       sortProperties(obj, sortedBy, isNumericSort, reverse) {
        sortedBy = sortedBy || 1; // by default first key
        isNumericSort = isNumericSort || false; // by default text sort
        reverse = reverse || false; // by default no reverse

    var reversed = (reverse) ? -1 : 1;

    var sortable = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            sortable.push([key, obj[key]]);
        }
    }
    if (isNumericSort)
        sortable.sort(function (a, b) {
            return reversed * (a[1][sortedBy] - b[1][sortedBy]);
        });
    else
        sortable.sort(function (a, b) {
            var x = a[1][sortedBy].toLowerCase(),
                y = b[1][sortedBy].toLowerCase();
            return x < y ? reversed * -1 : x > y ? reversed : 0;
        });
    return sortable; // array in format [ [ key1, val1 ], [ key2, val2 ], ... ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an object of nested objects in javascript (maybe using lodash?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554839/sorting-an-object-of-nested-objects-in-javascript-maybe-using-lodash)

Answer (score 0):

If you sort something definitely the outcome should be an array which lists your sorted items in ascending or descending order. Even if you assigned the sorted array to a object with key, value pairs, it will become unsorted.